# Did centering within a DataGrid column change from Flex3 to Flex4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In Flex3, I could center a checkbox within a datagrid column using this:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn textAlign="center" itemRenderer="mx.controls.CheckBox"/>
```

That is, the centering is specified on the column.  In Flex4, that doesn't work.  I have to put the centering on the renderer rather than on the column.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn>
   <mx:itemRenderer>
      <mx:Component>
         <mx:CheckBox textAlign="center"/>
      </mx:Component>
   </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Does anyone know if this change from Flex3 to Flex4 was intentional?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the checkbox inside a canvas:

```
<mx:Component>
     <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%">
         <mx:CheckBox textAlign="center"/>
     </mx:Canvas>
 </mx:Component>
```